# CYPRESS REMIX Error: Webpack Compilation Error

Tags: webpack, cypress, remix.run

Im currently using the indie Stack from Remix, but trying to run the  test with cypress send me that error in the browser of cypress, does anyone have a similiar issue? im using the indie stack from scratch

https://github.com/remix-run/indie-stack

this is the complete error.

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js 429:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (429:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition -- types are not aware of older browsers that don't implement `labels`
|   if (element.labels !== undefined) {
>     return element.labels ?? [];
|   }
| 
 @ ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/dist/index.js 9:11-42
 @ ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/dist/add-commands.js
 @ ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/add-commands.js
 @ ./cypress/support/e2e.ts
    at handle (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:180:23)
    at finalCallback (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:257:39)
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:306:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:33
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at /Users/poolortega/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.8.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)

This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code. This is usually caused by:

- A missing file or dependency
- A syntax error in the file or one of its dependencies

Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to @RémiPeron for finding the issue.

This is the guideline I used to solve:

**Check for fix**

First check for a fix to the problem, go to `https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library` and  look for a release number higher than `8.0.3`. This problem is likely to be fixed on the next release.

**Resolve before fix appears**

Specifically, the steps to resolve are:

- close the app and Cypress if running
- go to folder `/remix-indie-stack/node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/node_modules` (where `/remix-indie-stack` is the root folder of your project)
- rename or delete sub-folder `@testing-library`
- go back to the project folder
- install the older version of `@testing-library/dom`

  - `npm install --save-dev @testing-library/dom@8.17.1`
  - OR `yarn add -D @testing-library/dom@8.17.1`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when updating my modules.

It seems that the latest update from @testing-library/dom (8.18.0) is creating the error with cypress and remix.
You should revert back to version 8.17.1.

May be link to this issue : https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/1169

Answer (score 1):

@Fody - Thanks for your comment. I have been facing this issue since 3 days. your steps cleared my concern.

In my case i only tried

> npm install --save-dev @testing-library/dom@8.17.1

and it worked for me.