# Cypress Error Error: Webpack Compilation Error ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/node_modules/

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, cypress, cypress-testing-library

AM trying to run my test and am getting this error below, I need help if anyone has faced  the same issue and found a solution

This is the error below

````
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/@testing-library/dom.esm.js 429:27
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (429:27)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|   // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition -- types are not aware of older browsers that don't implement `labels`
|   if (element.labels !== undefined) {
>     return element.labels ?? [];
|   }
| 
 @ ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/dist/index.js 9:11-42
 @ ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/dist/add-commands.js
 @ ./node_modules/@testing-library/cypress/add-commands.js
 @ ./cypress/support/e2e.ts
    at Watching.handle [as handler] (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-preprocessor/dist/index.js:180:23)
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:99:9
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Watching._done (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:98:28)
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:73:19
    at Compiler.emitRecords (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:54:20
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:482:27
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2818:7
    at done (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:3522:9)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:464:33
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:143:16
    at /Users/zudemwango/Library/Caches/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:61:14
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:188:23)```
````

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73768031/cypress-remix-error-webpack-compilation-error-node-modules-testing-library-d) for a resolution.

Comment: That resolution is for a remix project and am not using it. When I remove all references and imports for @testing-library/cypress the tests run but I want to use the commands from @testing-library/cypress

Comment: The Remix project doesn't affect the fix, you have the same error - if you follow the steps you will resolve it.